# sum of all the columns values in the given dataframe and display output in in a new data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have tried the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd(C1,columns=['School-A','School-B','School-C','School-D','School-E'])
sum_column = daeframet.sum(axis=0)
print (sum_column)
```

I am getting the below error

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

**Data:**

[image: datframe]

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: Please do not post links. Display your dataframe in the question. Also, is `daeframet` a typo or your actual code ? That is not defined anywhere. `df.sum()` should work well.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from calling the module `pd` as a function. It's difficult to know which function you should be calling from pandas without knowing what `C1` is, but if it is a dictionary or a pandas data frame, try:

```
import pandas as pd

# common to abbreviate dataframe as df
df = pd.DataFrame(C1, columns=['School-A','School-B','School-C','School-D','School-E'])

sum_column = df.sum(axis=0)

print(sum_column)
```

Answer (score 0):

using sum will only return a series and not a dataframe, there are many ways you can do this. Lets try using `select_dtypes` and the `to_frame()` method

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(5)

df = pd.DataFrame({'class' : ['first','second','third','fourth','fifth'],
             'School A' : np.random.randint(1,50,5),
             'School B' : np.random.randint(1,50,5),
             'School C' : np.random.randint(1,50,5),
             'School D' : np.random.randint(1,50,5),
             'School E' : np.random.randint(1,50,5)})
print(df)
        class  School A  School B  School C  School D  School E
0   first        36        10        49        16        14
1  second        15         9        31        40        12
2   third        48        37        17        17         2
3  fourth        39        40         8        28        48
4   fifth        17        28        13        45        31

new_df = (df.select_dtypes(include='int').sum(axis=0).to_frame()
     .reset_index().rename(columns={0 : 'Total','index' : 'School'}))
print(new_df)
     School  Total
0  School A    155
1  School B    124
2  School C    118
3  School D    146
4  School E    107
```

### Edit

seems like there are some typos in your code :

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(C1,columns=['School-A','School-B','School-C','School-D','School-E'])
sum_column = dataframe.sum(axis=0)
print (sum_column)
```

will return the sum as a series, and also sum the text columns by way of string concatenation :

```
class       firstsecondthirdfourthfifth
School A                            155
School B                            124
School C                            118
School D                            146
School E                            107
dtype: object
```